# Life time of an unnamed temporary constructed in if condition expression

Tags: c++

How Standard defines the life time of a temporary object constructed during evaluation of an `if` condition expression?

I looked for this information and found something similar in an example to point [10] in $1.9, page 10. (I'm referring here to Final Draft of the new specification.) Yet still it wasn't clear (enough) for me and since Visual C++ acted differently than my understanding of that example I decided to ask.

Please provide proper references to specification.

---

If you name the object it persists for the entire `if` (so both `true` block and `false` block but is destroyed before `if` ends).

For example:

```
if ( MyClass x = f() ) { /* ... */ } else { /* ... */ }
nextInstruction();
```

`x` can be used in both `if` blocks but gets destroyed before `nextInstruction` gets called.

But what if you don't name it?

```
if ( f() ) { /* ... */ } else { /* ... */ }
nextInstruction();
```

In my understanding of the referenced part of specification the value returned by `f()` will be destroyed before execution enters one of the blocks (either for `true` or for `false`).

However Visual C++ destroys that temporary object as if it was named. *(**EDIT:** as Tino Didriksen pointed out Visual C++ does work well here. And indeed now I confirm that as well. I must have made a mistake when looking at initial tests results!)*

---

This does matter in some edge cases (lets not discuss here how likely they are or whether it is good to write code that way...).

For example lets have:

```
class ScopedLock {
public:
  ~ScopedLock() { if ( isLocked() ) unlock(); }

  operator bool() const { return isLocked(); }

  /* ... */

};
```

Now if we have code like:

```
if ( ScopedLock lock = resource.lock() ) { /* ... */ }
```

we can be sure that when execution enters the `true` block we own the resource and that it will not be unlocked before we leave that block.

But what if someone wrote it like this:

```
if ( resource.lock() ) { /* ... */ }
```

Now it is crucial at which point the destructor for the temporary `ScopedLock` will be called. Because it determines whether this code is correct or not (in the sens of resource usage). (Again lets skip discussing whether writing such code is bad in general. That is not the point of this question...)

Comment: fully compilable example would be much better, then code snippets. Your question is difficult to understand because of complexity. Took me a while to understand, but is good :)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

As far as I can tell, Visual C++ is wrong in this regard.

Indeed, a temporary is (almost always) destroyed at the end of the full expression in which it is created:

> §12.2/3: [...]Temporary objects are destroyed as the last step in evaluating the
>   full-expression that (lexically) contains the point where they
>   were created

Looking at the definition of a selection statement (`if` and `switch`), we can see that the condition is an expression:

```
§6.4:
selection-statement:
  if ( condition ) statement
  if ( condition) statement else statement
  switch ( condition ) statement

condition:
  expression
  type-specifier-seq declarator = assignment-expression
```

So any temporaries created in the condition should be destroyed before executing the following statement (unless bound to a reference-to-const).

The behavior when introducing a new name in the condition is specified in §6.4/3:

> A name introduced by a declaration in a condition [...] is in
>   scope from its point of declaration until the end of the substatements
>   controlled by the condition.

So in your example, `x` is in scope in the two branches of the `if`, and destroyed before evaluating `nextInstruction()`.

Answer (score 13):

> However Visual C++ destroys that temporary object as if it was named.

No it doesn't...

Given the code

```
#include <iostream>

struct S {
    S() { std::cout << "S()" << std::endl; }
    S(const S&) { std::cout << "S(const S&)" << std::endl; }
    ~S() { std::cout << "~S()" << std::endl; }
    operator bool() const { return true; }
};

int main() {
    std::cout << "main 1" << std::endl;

    if (S s = S()) {
        std::cout << "if 1" << std::endl;
    }
    else {
        std::cout << "else 1" << std::endl;
    }

    std::cout << "main 2" << std::endl;

    if (S()) {
        std::cout << "if 2" << std::endl;
    }
    else {
        std::cout << "else 2" << std::endl;
    }

    std::cout << "main 3" << std::endl;
}
```

GNU g++ 4.5.1 and g++ 4.7.0 and VC++ 2010 and VC++ 2012 have the exact same output:

```
main 1
S()
if 1
~S()
main 2
S()
~S()
if 2
main 3
```

where the named temporary is destroyed after the if/else and the unnamed temporary is destroyed at the end of the condition.

Comment: Yes! You are right. I have re-run my test again to compare and found out that it has same results as yours. I don't know what is wrong with me. Must have somehow weirdly misinterpret console output...

Comment: @AdamBadura can you mark this as the correct answer?

Comment: @Catskul Why would I? It doesn't really answer my question in the first place. It only shows that I was wrong about Visual C++ behavior. The answer that I marked as correct quoted Standard answering my question.

Comment: I got the impression from reading this thread that the original question involved a misunderstanding and that visual studio did not produce the incorrect behavior. Am I mistaken?

Comment: The answer to "Please provide proper references to specification." is clearly not my answer - I just seriously doubted VC++ got it wrong, so I tested it, and showed that it behaved correctly. It is a de facto answer, but he wanted a de jure one.

Comment: by the way what is the expression evaluation value  for S s = S() inside of the if condition?  Is it the address of newly created s  instance  ?

Answer (score 3):

This is what I found in "The Design and Evolution of C++" on page 145:

```
void h(String s1, String s2)
{
    const char* p;
    if (p = s1+s2) {
        // ...
    }
}
```

> Does the destruction of the object holding `s1+s2` take place at the end of the condition or at the end of the whole `if` statement? The answer is that the object holding `s1+s2` will be destroyed at the end of the condition.